Store type of interface and class inhereting the interface as object for later use
I'm trying to create a class where I can pass in an interface and the class which inherits the interface. I will later call a method and use the interface and class to register a Transient service. But I can't figure out how store the types.
This is what I got so far:
public sealed class Transient : AppFeatureBase, IAppFeatureBase
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _vals = [];

    public static void Add<TService, TImplementation>() where TService : class
                                                        where TImplementation : class, TService
    {
        _vals.Add(TService, TImplementation);
    }

    public static IServiceCollection Add(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return services.AddTransient<??, ??>();
    }
}


If you want to use the generic overload of AddTransient then you have to specify the data types directly in the code. If you don't want to specify the data types directly in the code then don't use the generic overload. Use a non-generic overload and specify the types at run time via Type objects. How you get those Type objects is completely up to you.

.AddTransient is just an extension, and you can use the overload which takes Type parameters, or just populate a ServiceDescriptor manually and add that. But I don't really see the point of the code you've written. Why delay the inevitable? Just call IServiceCollection.AddTransient directly.

@JeremyLakeman I have created a little system for configuring the asp.net core site. so I need to be able to control when the different features are added. It works great, but this issue is bothering me. There must be a simple solution, it shouldn't be so hard. Or maybe it should ;)

You don't need to convince me (and you shouldn't bother), but you should always question if adding a layer of indirection is worth the cost. Ask yourself, in what ways is your configuration system going to be better? What are the overheads? And will this be worth the additional complexity, maintenance cost, and education of future contributors....

I ended up with this:
public sealed class Transient(Type service, Type obj) : AppFeatureBase(Features.Transient), IAppFeatureBase
{
    public Type Interface => service;
    public Type Implementation => obj;
}

In use:
new Transient(typeof(ILocalRepo), typeof(LocalRepo))

if (features.Exists(Features.Transient))
{
    foreach (Transient feat in features.Where(feat => feat.Type == Features.Transient))
    {
        builder.Services.AddTransient(feat.Interface, feat.Implementation);
    }
}

